# Why ~0 >> 1 doesn't shift the bit?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I just learn from K&R c book chapter 2, let's say i have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
    printf("0x%016llx\n", ~0); //0x00000000ffffffff

    printf("0x%016llx\n", ~0 >> 1); //0x00000000ffffffff
    printf("0x%016llx\n", 0x00000000ffffffff >> 1); //0x000000007fffffff
    return 0;
}
```

I expect `~0 >> 1` will give `0x000000007fffffff` like how `0x00000000ffffffff >> 1` do, which `~0` has the value of `0x00000000ffffffff`.

Why `~0 >> 1` doesn't shift the bit ?

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behavior, thus all possible results are equally valid. To fix the UB, change `llx` to `x`. Then, to get the behavior you want, change `~0` to `~0u`.

Comment: @Robᵩ - nice comment.  Should be an answer.

Comment: @林果皞: `~0` on your platform is not `0x00000000ffffffff`, as you incorrectly assumed. It is just `0xffffffff`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `llx` format specifier expects an `unsigned long long` argument, but you're passing in an `int`.

The shift is not giving you what you expect because `~0` results in an `int` with a negative value.  So doing a right shift preserves the sign bit, i.e. a `1` bit is shifted in to the left.

Put the `ULL` suffix on your integer constants to force them to be the proper type:

```
printf("0x%016llx\n", ~0ULL);
printf("0x%016llx\n", ~0ULL >> 1);
printf("0x%016llx\n", 0x00000000ffffffffULL >> 1);
```

Then you'll get the expected output:

```
0xffffffffffffffff
0x7fffffffffffffff
0x000000007fffffff
```

Because the values are now unsigned, a `0` bit always gets shifted into the left.

Answer (score 2):

This code ...

> ```
> printf("0x%016llx\n", ~0)
> ```

... and your other analogous examples exhibit undefined behavior because the type (`int`) of `~0` does not correspond to the corresponding field descriptor, `%llx`, which requires an `unsigned long long int`.

Evaluating the expression `~0 >> 1` exhibits implementation-defined (not *un*defined) behavior, because the standard explicitly says

> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions [, but] If
>   `E1` has  a  signed  type  and  a  negative  value,  the resulting value is implementation-defined.

(C2011, 6.5.7/5)

This arises at least in part because there are two incompatible interpretations of a right shift of a negative number:

- an *arithmetic* shift, in which the result has the same sign as the left operand, and
- a *logical* shift, in which positions vacated by the shift are always filled with zeroes.

Implementations get to choose (freely, not just between those alternatives).  In practice, that means portable code should not rely on such operations.